# Change default Outlook 2007 paste format to 'Keep Text Only'

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007

When you paste text into an email in Outlook 2007 the default is to 'Keep source formatting' which I very rarely need. Is there a way to change the default to 'Keep Text Only' without installing a separate utility?

[image: Outlook 2007 paste menu]

Comment: I don't have 2007 installed, but what happens when you select "Set Default Paste?"

Comment: Doh! I've looked at that menu hundreds of times and never noticed that... and of course it does exactly what I want.

Comment: I put that in an answer so you can accept it to close out the question.  We've all done stuff like that before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click "Set Default Paste" and make keep text only your default.

Answer (score 0):

Or, in any Office program with that huge round logo in the top left corner: click that logo to access the preferences.

(In my experience settings may not always be remembered well. After changing I always close Office, hoping it helps to save the preferences.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more universal solution, which can remove any and all formatting from copied text, you can try Puretext. This little Windows tool will let you unformat any text currently in the clipboard, so when you paste back, it is pasted as plain text. Very useful when pasting commands from a formatted document where the formatting translates in extra characters on the command line for Linux, for example. Also, it is for ALL Windows applications, not only Outlook.

You can look at this great utility at:

http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/

Comment: Cool, but if you are going to use a 3rd party utility you might as well get one that includes that capability AND a clipboard manager, like ClipX (http://bluemars.org/clipx/) or Ditto (http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/).